# Heroku page displays an error while "heroku logs" do not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Heroku-hosted Rails site is showing that an error has occurred, but when I run `heroku logs` no error is listed. It does show the action that is causing the error but it lists it the same way it does every other successful action.

This is the first time `heroku logs` hasn't displayed the errors for this site. Has anyone had this problem before and found a solution?

Answer (score 23):

For Rails 4, add `rails_12factor` gem to your Gemfile in order to get detailed logs of your application. Additionally it fixes some other weired problems about Heroku too.

Add this to your Gemfile:

> gem 'rails_12factor'

Comment: What are the performance ramifications for enabling rails_12factor in production?

Comment: There's no direct performance ramifications of the gem. It just configures the app to log to STDOUT and serve static assets.

Answer (score 13):

I've noticed this too. Heroku has several logging levels. You should try this:

```
heroku config:add LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
heroku addons:upgrade logging:expanded
```

Then go to your app and get ready to hit the page with an error. But before you do do this:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

And you should be able to see the errors in you console.