# Email for user confirmation not sending in production. Rails, Heroku, Devise, Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, devise, confirmation

I've looked all over Google and stackoverflow for an answer, but none of them work.
I'm trying to set up smtp emailing for user confirmation after signing up. It works fine in development. Even with MailCatcher on, it bypasses it somehow and sends to the right email from my assigned gmail.

Here's what's in development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}
```

Here's what's in production.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'http'} #I've also tried it without ":protocol => 'http'"
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :authentication => :plain,   # I've also tried :login
     :enable_starttls_auto => true,  # Also tried tls => true
     :user_name => 'myemail@gmail.com',
     :password => 'mypassword'
   } #I've also tried having the attribute :domain => 'myapp.herokuapp.com',
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'  #It still sends from myemail@gmail.com even with this line uncommented.
```

I don't know how to paste out my entire 7 pages (in word document) worth of heroku logs in code block, so I've pasted them in a google doc.

google doc of heroku logs (I believe I highlighted the part where it started to go wrong on page 1-2):

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G-cCX7T1sPL5XtjyjHRaWmzfaBbWkuTR2edsDmDm1Pc/edit?usp=sharing

I'm not sure where it's finding the correct email to send from in development. I'm still a novice at this.

edit: I just found out that users that were registered before adding confirmation are not able to log in as well, so it might be a users problem with heroku. But everything still works fine in development.

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might miss this `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`

Comment: I had that on the production.rb file before, but deleted it when I was told it wasn't needed.

Comment: I couldn't find any error message from your logs, it was cut off somehow I think.

Comment: Additionally, I got a problem with Gmail and I had to accept the permission for external access (there is a message on the top when you login to your Gmail). Otherwise, you will meet SMTPAuthenticationError. [check it out](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2010/03/detecting-suspicious-account-activity.html)

Comment: I never got a message/warning at the top of my Gmail. I also checked the last login details and it shows that it was logged in through SMTP in development, but it didn't log in when I tried in production. How can I find the error message if heroku logs is not showing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6766529/1881153 that may help you about Heroku Log Level.

Comment: thanks that link helped a lot. I edited the google doc link in my original post to the latest heroku logs. are you able to find out what's wrong now?

Comment: "NameError (undefined local variable
 or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x007f520117cfa0>)" Have you migrate your database on Production mode? It seem like your database schema is missing confirmed_at column. The problem is from your Devise model, not your Gmail's configuration, I think.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I forgot all about migrating to the heroku database.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your gmail asked for captcha for sending the mail or not. and to debug the error please make `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` on your production.rb .Please check the similar question [Net::SMTPAuthenticationError when sending email from Rails app (on staging environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir)

Comment: I checked the page and made sure my code mirrors their solution.  I also checked the captcha. Google said: "Account access enabled

Please try signing in to your Google account again from your new device or application."

It's still not working.

Comment: Also, since it works in development (in that it actually sends from gmail), could it be different for production?

Comment: yes some times it's create problem in production. as google ask for captcha. please follow the previous link and also check what error is there for sending the email

Comment: Gmail says that access to the account has been enabled. How do I check what error there is? On Heroku, it just says "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Comment: the heroku logs are uploaded on speedyshare. I linked to it in the original post. I'm not sure how to paste long lines of code without having to manually type 4 spaces before each line. If you're afraid it's a malicious download, I can put it in a google doc.

Comment: It's not letting me post the link in the comments. I added the google doc to the original post

Comment: I can not see any error present in the log. have you set config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true in production.rb and please check the log what errors its showing in production.

Comment: Please check the mail sending method to your heroku console also.

Comment: I do have config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true in production. How do I check the mail sending method in my heroku console?

Comment: just run in your consloe 'heroku run console' and call the method in it.

Comment: I'm not sure what method to call, I'm using devise to send email authentication. But in any case, I updated the heroku logs after setting the heroku log level to debug. Are you able to tell what's wrong with the updated logs?

Comment: I thing i can see is " NameError (undefined local variable
 or method `confirmed_at'" from the log can you please check and confirm it.