# Gmail as ActionMailer deployment in heroku issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail

I don't understand what's happening with Gmail as ActionMailer. It's not sending any confirmation emails when deployed in heroku. I could use it comfortably with development. Problem arises when I deploy it with heroku.

These are my settings in production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port    => 587,
  :domain  => 'floating-castle-4592.herokuapp.com',
  :user_name  => 'XXXXX@gmail.com',
  :password  => ENV['PASS'],
  :authentication  => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Setting in development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port    => 587,
  :domain  => 'gmail.com',
  :authentication     => :login,
  :user_name          => 'XXXXX@gmail.com',
  :password           => ENV['PASS'],
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I tried swapping 'login' with 'plain', domain: 'gmail.com' with 'blahblah.herokuapp.com'. I tried all permutations and combinations. No success so far. I tried ":openssl_verify_mode => 'none'" option in smtp_settings too. That didn't bring me any success! I seriously don't understand what's happening here.

I will edit post if you need more information.

I have posted error free logs before.
 With reference to this post I dig deeper into the logging levels to find out the error [stackoverflow.com/a/6766529/1881153](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6766529/1881153)

**New Developments:**

Heroku log shows the error as

```
ArgumentError (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well! Removing ENV['PASS'] with password as a string 'xxxx' worked for me. Weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using gmail in production, I would recommending using one of the `freemium` Heroku add-ons to handle SMTP -- either [`SendGrid`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid) or [`Mandrill`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mandrill)

We have this setup working with SendGrid:

```
  #config/environments/production.rb
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, Rich. Will consider that option for sure. I want to know why isn't this working.

Comment: Answer member's question, then post your opinion on best practice.

Comment: If you're not happy with the answer, write your own.